# Change quality of PDF rendered using PDFsharp

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfsharp

Can we reduce the quality of PDF rendered using PDFsharp? 
I have to render files containing thousands of pages. Due to this, the resulting files sometimes occupy more than 100 MB memory space which is inconvenient. 
A PDF is rendered from an Excel sheet. There are no images or charts. Only the number of rows in the Excel is very high. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried asking this [on their forums](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/)? Seems like a more appropriate place to ask about how to perform a specific action using a particular library.

Comment: Furthermore you say nothing about the nature of the pdf you create. E.g. Does it include images? Does it include regions appearing identically on many pages?  ...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes, I posted a question there too.

Comment: @mkl No, there are no images. It just contains a table. I converted an Excel sheet actually.

Comment: Unless the excel Export generates many redundant commands, it might be hard to compress.

Comment: It uses the `AddParagraph()` command many times. Does that count?

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of PDFsharp it is up to you to reduce the resolution of images or the JPEG quality to optimize the file size.

.NET provides functions that can accomplish that.